# Mixing javascript, jQuery and PHP, newline

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, newline

Ok, so I have a few things here:

Javascript:

```
desc = "line 1 \n line 2"
```

jQuery:

```
$("#msg").text(desc);
```

PHP:

```
const NUM = 555;
```

What I want, is to change the text of the `<p>` with the id of `msg`, so that it would contain a piece of text with a number of lines, and in one of them the number from the PHP constant.

Like so:

Line 1
Line 2 555, Line 2 continued 
Line 3

My problem is how do I mix them all? I tried the following:

`var desc = "line 1 \n line2" + <?php echo NUM ?> +"\n line 3";` and that doesn't work.

Comment: "and that doesn't work." What doesn't work? Do you get an error, or is it in wrong order?

Comment: Try `<?php echo constant("NUM")?>` instead?

Comment: What's the expected output? I'm not understanding `line 1` `line 2` `line 3`.

Comment: The expected input is just 3 lines of text, while in one of them I have the number which is stored in the PHP constant. About the error - I get 'Unexpected token ILLEGAL'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues with your code:

- PHP constants should be defined using `define("CONSTANT_NAME", "VALUE");` syntax;
- `\n` has no effect inside HTML tag (if you dont apply `white-space: pre;` or `pre-wrap`);
- `<?php echo NUM; ?>` should be wrapped with `"` or should be inside JavaScript string;
- `$("#msg").text(desc)` will remove all tags from `desc`, thus you need to use `.html(desc)` instead.

What you need is something like this:

**PHP**

```
define("NUM", 555);
```

**JavaScript**

```
var desc = "line 1<br/>line2 <?php echo NUM; ?><br/>line 3";
$("#msg").html(desc);
```

Comment: +1 because this looks right, but the question is not very clear at all ... so i can't tell.

Comment: @frrlod do you understand why it worked? that's more important than just having something that works.

Comment: @frrlod I updated the answer with description what was wrong with your code.