# Can we mix PHP and jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, mixins

Is it a common thing to mix PHP and JavaScript?
Lets say I declared a PHP function returning a string:

```
function myPhpFunction(some_string) {
    return 'blablabla' . some_string; 
}
```

Then once the DOM is loaded is it correct to do something like:

```
$(document).on('click', '.my_class', function() {
   $(this).html(<?PHP myPhpFunction('some_string'); ?>);
});
```

Comment: Nope. You are trying to run server code on the browser/client side. You need to request the string from the function via an Ajax call to the server.

Comment: You can mix it as much as you want, the two have nothing to do with each other. PHP is executed on the server, and javascript in the browser, they don't interact at all really, what you're trying to do is output something on the serverside, and use it on the clientside, and that is surely possible, as long as the file is parsed by PHP before being sent to the browser.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mixing javascript, jQuery and PHP, newline](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16445663/mixing-javascript-jquery-and-php-newline)

Comment: aside from all the correct answers regarding the distinction serverside: PHP <-> clientside: JS/JQuery, your example might still work, just not exactly as you expect it to work: if your JS code is in a file that gets interpreted by the PHP runtime (for example if it is part of a template), the `<?php something ?>` bits will be executed. Just not onLoad in the clients DOM, but as part of the request on the server _before_ it is send to the client

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly like that, but there are ways to achive what you want to do!

But first, some basics:

PHP is a server side langauge. It processes data, makes HTML, send the HTML and javascript back to the browser.

Javascript is a client side language. It works in the browser and not on the server side (apart from node, but we won't go into that).

What you want to do, is pass some information from your PHP to your javascript.

You would put the javascript code you have there, in a PHP file. The PHP code will then replace that section with the resulting string, which will result in that value being sent to the client in the HTML.

If your javascript function or event or whatever, is ran multiple times, it won't be able to run the PHP function again, as it only runs once to generate the text of the HTML which is sent back to the client.

Hopefully that all makes sense.

P.S. remember to search stackoverflow for your question before asking it. I'm pretty sure someone has asked and answered this question before. Normally it will be flagged, but I'm feeling nice today, so you get an answer.

Feel free to ask further questions if I don't make complete sense.

Comment: By your question, I'm guessing you're new to this. jquery is not the same as javascript. Javascript is your language, jquery is a library. Just so you know =]